# How do I get Apache mod_cache to cache?

Tags: apache, caching, httpd.conf

I've gotten Apache mod_cache to work as intended on a Windows server running Apache 2.2, but I'm having trouble getting it running on a Linux cpanel server to which I have root access.

Here's what I know:

1) mod_cache and mod_disk_cache are both compiled into Apache (confirmed with "httpd -l")

2) My httpd.conf is configured like this

    
        CacheRoot /home/accountname/apache-cacheroot
        CacheEnable disk /

3) I've restarted Apache after all configuration changes

4) I know that section of the httpd.conf is being processed (I put some unrelated commands in there to debug.)

5) The file I request displays the current time via php, and it does not change on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

> ...it does not change on subsequent requests

It sounds like your caching *is* working. If it did change on every request, then the request is being served by PHP instead of Apache's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enabling the modules with `a2en cache` and `a2en disk_cache` ?

Do not forget to restart the server after doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what your have your CacheRoot set to, you may need to change the permissions to make the permissions 777.